# inputbox seperation css different in ff and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

this thing has irritated me a lot . ive used a html reset css code and added my simple code of 2 different inputboxes one below other , the total spacing in chrome  and ff,ie are different.

chrome has a bit wider space whereas ff and ie have 0 space between the input boxes.

here's the rendering of it

http://jsfiddle.net/LLsyw/

here's the html part of it

```
<div id="div2">

<div class='input'>
<input type='text' />
</div>
<div class='input' >
<input type='text' class='second' placeholder='data'/>
</div>

</div>
```

and here's the css

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

could someone plz point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly give your inputs their own margin. The css reset code doesn't even address the input elements. if you really want to reset everything why not do this:

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
outline:0;
font-size:100%;
vertical-align:baseline;
background:transparent;
}
```

By using an incomplete list in the reset, browsers are left to choose their own defaults for the unlisted elements.

Answer (score 0):

use specific Css reset for the input element:`input {margin:0;padding:0;display:block;}`